# PG Admin not importing .csv file

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, pgadmin

I was happily importing .csv files until today when PG Admin (on Windows machine) decided not to. I get the "Import/Export Job Successfully created" box and then nothing. Not the Green Success box or the red fail box. No error messages.  I've created a new environment. I've deleted the database and created a new one.  No joy.

Comment: I should add I've checked the .csv files. Data is there and the headers match. This file worked yesterday.